# Is it true that the a generic trajectory of the logistic map ${x_{n+1}}=4 x_n(1- x_n)$ can come arbitrarily close to $(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})$

Tags: chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I know that at r=4, the map exhibits chaotic behaviour for almost every trajectory except for very few which lead to fixed periodic behaviour. For this reason, I am inclined to say that the above question is true as there will exist some initial condition which fulfills the criteria of coming close (in an infinite cycle for example).

However I am hesitant with the wording "generic trajectory" which has me thinking it is referring to any trajectory which as I've mentioned isn't true in a small number of cases. Any advice on this answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: 'Generic' in a _technical_ context has a couple of different meanings; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property . From a measure-theoretic sense, where the definition is roughly 'the set of points that don't come close is of measure zero', this certainly holds. It probably holds topologically as well but I haven't tried to check that closely.

Answer (score 1):

The logistic system you are describing has invariant measure
$$\mu(dx)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$$

So, there is a set $B$ with  $\mu(B)=0$ such that any trajectory $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ with $x_0\in (0,1)\setminus B$  visits any neighborhood of any point in $(1,0)$ infinitely often. This follows for example, from the ergodic theorem which in this case states that for $\mu$ almost any initial condition $x_0$  in $(0,1)$,

$$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\mathbb{1}_A(x_k)$$
So if $\mu(A)>0$, then $x_n$ visits $A$ inifnitely often (the exceptional initial conditions, if there are any, have $\mu$ measure $0$.

Since $\mu$ is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure (in terms of measure $0$),  the set of exceptional initial values is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

---

A short description is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Chaos_and_the_logistic_map)

Comment: So would this be true for a "generic trajectory" which I take to mean any initial condition in the interval [0,1]?

Comment: @sb122: $\mu$-almost surely yes, that is, with the exception of initial values in some set of $\mu$-measure zero, the trajectories of the system will visit any subinterval contained in $(0,1)$ infinitely many times. Generic in probability and ergodic theory  means that the set of exceptions (in this case exceptional initial values) form a set of probability (measure) $0$.